# Deletar dados de uma tabela MYSQL com Java

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, java-ee, jdbc

Estou tentando deletar os dados de uma tabela com *Java* mas por algum motivo o código não está funcionando. Trecho do código abaixo:

```
    public void excluir(ModeloObjeto modelo) throws Exception{
            Connection conexao = CriaConexao.getConexao();
            PreparedStatement ps;
            ps = conexao.prepareCall("DELETE FROM `funcionalidade_celular` WHERE `nome_cel` LIKE ?");
            ps.setString(1, "'"+modelo.getModelo()+"'");
            executar(ps);
    }
```

Todas as outras funcionalidades estão normais usando a mesma logica, mas somente a de excluir não está funcionando. Já printei o resultado de `modelo.getModelo()` e fiz o teste com o resultado da saida no Workbench e funcionou perfeitamente, mas na hora de excluir pela pagina web ele não exclui.

Método `executar`:

```
public void executar(PreparedStatement ps) throws Exception{
        if(ps == null){
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        try {
            ps.execute();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        finally{
            ps.close();
        }
    }
```

Metodo `getConexao()`:

```
public static Connection getConexao(){
        if(conexao == null){
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASS);
            } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CriaConexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return conexao;
    }
```

Comment: Bruno, copie aqui o código do método executar e do getConexao. Pode ser algum detalhe nesses métodos, como por exemplo o setAutoCommit.

Comment: Pronto, editei e coloquei os dois métodos,

Comment: Olá Bruno, ao executar o seu *excluir* é exibido algo no *console*?

Answer (score 1):

Retire as crases do nome da tabela e da coluna e também as aspas que envolvem a passagem de parâmetro em `ps.setString()`

Seu código fica assim:

```
 public void excluir(ModeloObjeto modelo) throws Exception{
        Connection conexao = CriaConexao.getConexao();
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ps = conexao.prepareCall("DELETE FROM funcionalidade_celular WHERE nome_cel LIKE ?");
        ps.setString(1, modelo.getModelo());
        executar(ps);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Analisando seu código, verifiquei 2 pontos importantes que provavelmente podem ser a causa de seu problema.

1. O retorno do `getModelo()` lhe trás o nome do celular do qual você quer usar como cláusula para deleção de seu registro no *banco de dados*, mas, o modelo em sua estrutura de dados se refere ao nome do celular(`nome_cel`) ?
2. Note que sua instância `conexao` não foi fechada, isso acarretará vazamento de memória de conexão podendo prejudicar no desempenho de sua aplicação, também poderá trazer brechas à algumas atividades maliciosas relacionadas à integridade do banco de dados. Por isso é essencial que feche a sua conexão usando o código: `conexao.close();` após executar sua ação desejada.

Comment: Sim, ele se refere ao nome_cel. E sobre fechar a conexão, vou implementar isso no meu código, não tinha percebido que não tinha feito

Comment: Ao realizar a implementação, dê um *build* na sua aplicação e *restart* no servidor.

Comment: Fiz a implementação mas infelizmente continua sem sucesso na remoção.

Comment: @BrunoTchaikovsky, é exibido algum erro em seu *console*? Faça o teste usando o `ps.executeUpdate();` no lugar do `ps.execute()`.